# Keytool list command shows incorrect keystore format

Tags: openssl, keytool, pkcs#11, pkcs#12, jks

I'm creating a keystore in the `pkcs12` format using command:

```
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in <cert> -inkey <key> -out mycert.p12 -name <name> -caname <caname>
```

Once created I' checking the created keystore:

```
> keytool -list -keystore mycert.p12 
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
...
```

It's shows the type `JKS`.

When I specify the type of the keystore explicitly the output seems correct:

```
> keytool -list -keystore mycert.p12 -storetype pkcs12
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE
```

Why does `keytool` incorrectly show the type of the keystore when the `storetype` is not specified? This behaviour seems incorrect for me, the command should either fail or do not show the keystore type if the tool can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 've may used a older keytool version than shipped with Java 8u192.

There was a bug [JDK-8193171](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193171) reportet with the same issue.

I had the same problem with my installed jdk 1.8.0_161 - after using (the current) version 8u201 the keystore-type was displayed correctly.